# What wallet do support 25-word (24 words + extra word) seed phrases

Tags: wallets, security, myetherwallet

I know only one wallet is supported 25 words seed phrase (24 words + [extra word](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/security-and-privacy/mnemonic-phrase-extra-word/)) is [MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com).

Are there else wallets that support 25 words seed phrases?

**UPDATE**:

I'm interested in wallets what can import/export 25 words seed phrase like MEW.

Answer (score 1):

The 25th (or 13th) word is often called "passphrase" or "password". Some other wallets that support this password are:

### Software

- MyCrypto (desktop application) - https://download.mycrypto.com

### Hardware

- Ledger wallets - https://ledger.com/
- Trezor wallets - https://trezor.io/

Note that the password of MetaMask is **not** used as mnemonic password. As far as I know, MetaMask does not support this feature.

Comment: It strange for me but when I read the manual it is supported only 12 words. I mean MyCrypto. Kinda, hardware wallets can't import/export seed phrases. Or am I wrong?

Comment: MyCrypto supports 13th/25th words, but it's labelled as "Passphrase". For hardware wallets, you can import an existing mnemonic phrase or set up a new one and set a passphrase afterwards.

Comment: ...and how I understand `passphrase` or `password` is not the same 13/25 word.  "Occasionally, this extra word is also referred to as a ‘password’, but this is misleading. It’s actually a 13th / 25th word to your phrase." https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/security-and-privacy/mnemonic-phrase-extra-word/

Comment: I just try to create a wallet in the desktop app and it suggests me only 12 words.

Comment: What version of MyCrypto you use, I use 1.7.13, the last version from the site.

Comment: You can specify it after creating the mnemonic phrase, when you unlock your account. On View & Send, select Mnemonic Phrase, and there is a field to enter the passphrase. The passphrase/13th/25th word is used as salt when deriving the master key from the mnemonic phrase (see [BIP-39 spec](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#From_mnemonic_to_seed)), so I think "passphrase" is technically more accurate than "13th/25th word" (and BIP-39 refers to it as passphrase as well).

Comment: How I understand `passphrase` encrypt seed phrase only, otherwise `13th/25th words` allow me to get new public/private keys. In other words, if I input the wrong `passphrase` it does not allow me to get access to my seed phrases only, if I input the wrong `13th/25th words` it allows me to get access to new public/private keys, i.e. to a new wallet, really not my, but new. I think this moment is discussed in KB of MEW. Maybe I'm wrong, 'cause I'm a beginner in this question.

Comment: "Passphrase" and "13th/25th" word refer to the exact same thing in this case. It doesn't encrypt anything, but rather results in different addresses being derived.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. Another question what version of MyCrypto you use? Unfortunately, there is no choice. I can create a wallet with 12 words only.

Comment: Any version should work. I'm using the latest version (1.7.13 IIRC). After you create the mnemonic phrase, just go to the View & Send page, choose the Mnemonic Phrase option and enter your passphrase there. You can't create a mnemonic phrase with a passphrase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123369/discussion-between-mr-je-and-morten).

Answer (score 1):

Coinomi (Android/Windows/IOS/Mac/Linux) Supports the 25th word it's called BIP39 Passphrase in app.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Unstoppable Wallet on iOS/Android supports this.